# Form with two submit buttons but only one shows at any given time

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to have two `submit` buttons defined within the same HTML form ?

Both buttons will perform the exact same function ..

Only one will show at a given time though .. Which one shows depends on the device being used by the user (resolved through `@media` queries) ..

Button technically two submit buttons will be defined in HTML .. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="sb" value="One">
  <input type="submit" name="sb" value="Two">
  <input type="submit" name="sb" value="Three">
</form>
```

Just put that in an HTML page, click the buttons, and look at the URL

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you can create buttons and set onclick javascript handler to send that form, if you don't wanna 2 submit inputs.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
@media device1 { 
    #device2submitbutton { 
        display:none; 
    } 
}
@media device2 { 
    #device1submitbutton { 
        display:none; 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="device1submitbutton" value="device1 submit"/>
<input type="submit" id="device2submitbutton" value="device2 submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You know you can actually use `<button>`'s in forms and they submit the form

```
<form action="">
    <button>Submit 1</button>
    <button>Submit 2</button>
</form>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSY7y/)

This makes sense they are treated as submit buttons because you wouldn't have a button to take you somewhere or something while your filling out a form.